# How to show only 1 window of an application when the application icon in dash-to-dock is pressed?

Tags: 18.04, window, ubuntu-dock, gnome-shell-extension, dash-to-dock

In Ubuntu 18.04, when several windows of the same application are initially minimized, and when I click on the application icon in dash-to-dock, all these minimized windows will appear altogether. This behaviour will result in a very messy desktop and require a user to have to minimize unwanted windows again.

Is there a way to just have just one of the application window appear instead of having the screen flooded with too many windows at once?

Comment: yes. It is the middle option in the extension settings for what to do on mouseclick?! You know where you find gnome extension setting, right? It is in gnome-tweaks -> extensions -> dashtodock gearsymbol.

Comment: Right mouse click in dock will present a menu. Left click on All Windows and then select the one you want from what is displayed.

Comment: @mondjunge Got it. dash-to-dock --> Behavior --> click-action --> gearwheel. Middle-Click action --> Show window previews .  How do I do similar setting using gsettings? In dconf editor, I could not find Customize middle-click behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the terminal, I discovered that I can use the below cmd to do what @mondjunge described for gnome-tweaks:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock middle-click-action 'previews'
```

Thus when I middle-click an App icon in dash-to-dock, a preview of opened App windows appears, and I can select the window I want to maximize from the preview.

Comment: A workaround, not the correct answer.

Comment: @vanadium do you have another solution in mind? Could you share it? Thanks.

Comment: For me, by default, a single window is activated. I thought i your case  org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock activate-single-window might be set to 'false', but in my case, that does not change the behaviour to what you describe (mind I am on 19.04). Check that setting. I was just suggesting that what you post is not a real solution, but only a workaround, which you should mention in your answer I think.

Comment: @vanadium The `activate-single-window` default value is `true` for dash-to-dock in Ubuntu 18.04 too. Toggling it had no effect; also did not do what I wanted. It seems @mondjunge solution is the only viable solution; the `gsettings` cmd I wrote here is the cmdline way to achieving @mondjunge solution.

Comment: On 19.04, I cannot reproduce your issue, even if all windows effectively are minimized. The dock always brings a single window on the front, a subsequent one with each subsequent click. So this may indeed be an issue in 18.04 that has been solved.